# Running a query over past date ranges

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a rather interesting problem which I first thought would be straight-forward, but it turned out to be more complicated.

I have data like this:

```
Date             User ID
2012-10-11         a
2012-10-11         b
2012-10-12         c
2012-10-12         d 
2012-10-13         e
2012-10-14         b
2012-10-14         e
...                ...
```

Each row has a Date, User ID couple which indicates that that user was active on that day. A user can appear on multiple dates and a date will have multiple users -- just like in the example. I have millions of rows like this which cover a time range of about 90 days.

Here's the question: For each day, I want to get the number of users who have not been active for the past 10 days. For instance, if the user "a" was active on 2012-05-31 and but hasn't been active on any of the days between 06-01 and 06-10, I want to count this user on 6/10. I wouldn't count him again on the following days though unless he becomes active and disappears again.

Can I do this in SQL or would I need to some kind of script to organize the data the way I want. What would be your recommendations? I use Hive.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Had to add +1 for being appreciative (which you also did on previous questions).

Comment: This isn't so hard in standard SQL, but Hive just offers a subset of SQL functionality.  Actually, expressing the functionality in Map-Reduce directly would be a bit challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this in Hive-compatible SQL.  Here is the idea.

1. For each user/date get the next date for the user.
2. Discard the original record if the next is less than 10 days after the current one.
3. Add 10 to the date
4. Aggregate and count

I am not sure of all the Hive functions for things like date.  Here is an example of how to do it:

```
select date+10, count(*)
from (select t.userid, t.date,
             min(case when tnext.date > t.date then tnext.date end) as nextdate
      from t left outer join
           t tnext
           on t.userid = tnext.userid
      group by t.userid, t.date
     ) t
where nextdate is null or nextdate - date >= 10
group by date+10;
```

Note that the inner subquery would be better written using:

```
on t.userid = tnext.userid and t2.date > t.date
```

However, I don't know if Hive supports such a join (it doesn't support non-equijoins and it not clear about whether one or all clauses have to be equal).

Comment: thank you Gordon for saving the day again :) This is awesome. one quick comment... I believe in line 9, "nextdate - date = 10" should be rather "nextdate - date > 10"?

Comment: @user1621315 . . . In the OP, it sounds like you want to count the user only on the first day of inactivity ("if the user "a" was active on 2012-05-31 and but hasn't been active on any of the days between 06-01 and 06-10, I want to count this user on 6/10. I wouldn't count him again").  Of course, this is your problem, so if the inequality solves your problem, go ahead!

Comment: @user1621315 . . . Duh.  Another example of code that should be smart enough to read my mind.

Comment: oh ok my last comment became unnecessary now. I greatly appreciate your time. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're right about the non-equijoin, but you can add a where clause, e.g. `on t.userid = tnext.userid where tnext.data > t.date`, which I believe, should eliminate the `case`. I like this solution, I think I have few tasks to use this on.

Comment: @libjack . . . I wasn't sure if Hive would support a non-equality clause in the `on` statement.  That is why I used the `case`.  If it supports it, then that is a good solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, right it doesn't, but can tack on the `where` clause after the `on` to solve that.